# What are all the options that a field can have in a mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So basically I am working with `mongodb` using `mongoose`. I would like to know what are all the potential options that a field can have in a `mongoose` schema. For example, a user schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
   {
      username: {
         required: true,
         unique: true,
      },
      email: {
         required: true,
         unique: true,
      },
   },
   {
      timestamps: true,
   }
);
```

Here the fields of the schema are username and email. The options for these fields are required and unique. What are ***ALL*** the options that a field can have in a `mongoose` Schema? I found schema options in the `mongoose` docs but it talks about `autoIndex` and all this other stuff that is not relevant to my question. So again my question is what are all the options that a field can have in a `mongoose` schema. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so me not knowing all the options kept ticking me off so I kept searching and eventually I stumbled across the part of the documentation that answered my question. So for anyone who also has this same question, go to this link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html. Do a ctrl f for "All Schema Types" and you'll find them :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe all schema options are provided here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schematypeoptions.html

By any chance website goes down, there list is as follows:

```
cast
default
immutable
index
ref
required
select
sparse
text
transform
type
unique
validate
```

As you can see, both of your given options are there as well. One problem that I see is the amount of examples provided in that page. I checked some other sources and found this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schematype.js

What you would need to do is to search for a field (let's say, `prototype.select` or `prototype.unique`), find something like this: `SchemaType.prototype.select = function select(val) {` and check comment above it. From what I have seen, only `type` doesn't appear to have any example, not sure why.